# Argo Workflows template - how to create conditional parameter based on runtime information

Tags: go-templates, argo-workflows

i have an argo workflow - where one of the templates needs to receive a parameter that depends on an input variable (in this case the repository).

```
arguments:
          parameters:
            - name: path-in-git-repo
              value: "{{ `{{= workflow.parameters.gitRepo == 'repo1' ? 'this/file' : 'that/file' }}` }}"
```

i have tried anything i could find in the argo repo (conditional dag / valueFrom expression / ...) and could not get this to work. This seems like such an easy problem - but has cost more multiple days already. Has anyone found a solution to conditional parameters or is this not how to solve it in argo? (do i need to trigger a different workflow for that repo?)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `arguments.parameters` is the right place to do this.

As per my understanding, it can be done while defining template's `inputs.parameters`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: steps-
spec:
  entrypoint: hello

  templates:
  - name: hello
    steps:
    - - name: hello
        template: whalesay
        arguments:
          parameters:
            - name: gitRepo 
              value: repo1

  - name: whalesay
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: gitRepo
      - name: path-in-git-repo
        value: "{{= inputs.parameters.gitRepo == 'repo1' ? 'this/file' : 'that/file' }}"
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
      args: ["{{inputs.parameters.path-in-git-repo}}"]
```

Comment: I tried something similar and it didn't work
`  entrypoint: virt-server
  arguments:
    parameters:
    - name: path-in-git-repo
        value: "{{= inputs.parameters.gitRepo == 'repo1' ? 'this/file' : 'that/file' }}"`

Comment: yes this will not work in `arguments.parameters` so do try to move it under `inputs.parameters`